# mod_rewrite redirect complex old url to new one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a complex URL that an old website used to use for a specific page. In the new, updated website, this URL became much shorter and much less complex (in fact, the old one doesn't exist no longer). I'm trying to redirect the old URL, when entered in the browser or linked to from an email, to the new, shorter, and actually existing URL.

I've tried countless of things but I'm just really bad at everything mod_rewrite related. Needless to say, I'm trying to do this in my .htaccess file.

Old url:
www.domain.com/Event.211.0.html?&tx_calendar_pi1%5Bf1%5D=1061&tx_calendar_pi1%5Bf4%5D=1519102800&cHash=b884377a19d2bc32558d8c3ae232bedf

New url:
www.domain.com/events/februarypowerlunch/

Any suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/events/februarypowerlunch/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\?(.*)\%(.*)\%(.*)=(.*)\%(.*)\%(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^     /events/februarypowerlunch/?  [R=302,L]
```

If it is Ok , change `302` with `301` to get permanent redirection .

Update :

if you want to match only `Event.211.0.html` do this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/events/februarypowerlunch/
RewriteRule ^(e|E)vent\.211\.0\.html    /events/februarypowerlunch/?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - but - how can this code redirect that specific, complex, unique URL to /events/februarypowerlunch/ ?

Comment: put it inside .htaccess file in main directory

Comment: Incredible, I have no clue how - but it works brilliantly. Thanks for helping me out!!!!

Comment: Except, other URL's that contain % and ? and = now rewrite to that new URL as well.. That shouldn't be happening. Is there a way to make "Event.211.0" a part of the URL that will be rewritten? So, that it only rewrites to the new URL when the submitted/entered URL contains "Event.211.0" ?

Comment: ok , let me make it and i will update it to you to cover this issue

Comment: The updated script doesn't work. The first one did, but it rewrote too much (too many other pages). The new script lines don't work. I tried different browsers.

Comment: it should work , did you change only this line RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\?(.*)\%(.*)\%(.*)=(.*)\%(.*)\%(.*)$  by only one line from new suggested lines?

Comment: Yes, I tried numerous of times but it doesn't seem to work... The first one does, with the update it doesn't.. :-(

Comment: try this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Event\.211\.0\.html  [NC]

Comment: I have no idea why man but it's not working. Again, the first solution works, but none of the others do. Maybe it's because I use TYPO3 which uses a bunch of other rewrite rules itself...